# JBOSS Only Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper

Tags: java, jboss, apache-poi, wildfly

When using Apache POI to create a Workbook object to process an input stream, I started receiving the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper

I stepped through and found it occurring on this first line of code in this snippet from the ContentTypeManager.class (from org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal):

```
private void parseContentTypesFile(InputStream in) throws InvalidFormatException {
    try {
        Document xmlContentTypetDoc = DocumentHelper.readDocument(in);
        NodeList defaultTypes = xmlContentTypetDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types", "Default");
        int defaultTypeCount = defaultTypes.getLength();
        ....
```

So that line DocumentHelper.readDocument(in) is using the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder and that is where the issue ultimately is, it is unable to create a DocumentBuilder.   I tried removing xercesImpl with no effect.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code runs successfully using a WildFly server, but fails under JBOSS.  We are moving to WildFly but in the meantime production still is running JBOSS.

Any thoughts on how to resolve the error?   The project also has tika-core and tika-parsers-standard-package dependencies and not sure if those are causing an issue under JBOSS.   Previously this had been working under JBOSS.

Update: My POM has these entries that are connected to issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? Do you have poi-ooxml in your pom?

Comment: Did you add org.dom4j in your dependencies

Comment: @siggemannen yes my POM has that.  I updated post above to include the relevant dependencies.  Thanks!!

Comment: @girish thanks for your feedback.  I did not have that and gave it a shot to add it.  It looks like that particular jar is from 2005 (there was only ever a version 1.0) and I get this error after adding to the POM:

Could not find artifact xerces:dom3-xml-apis:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Funny thing is I can navigate and find that JAR there at this address: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xerces/dom3-xml-apis/1.0/

But I have a suspicion this JAR is no longer needed since it is super old now.

Comment: I tried adding xml-apis 2.0.2 dependency as well with no success (though it still works successfully running under WildFly, just not JBOSS).

Comment: Just created a new Java project and added the below dependency in the maven   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency> with  below:  import org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper; import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.Document;

Comment: @girish - I figured out answer below, but I was able to debug and figure out the issue was DocumentHelper trying to use  javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.   DocumentBuilder wanted to use a logging engine that had been excluded for WildFly.  It was a strange error and the logging issues in Java always get me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue and wanted to follow-up.   In order to get the apps running under WildFly and I had to add some logging exclusions because with WildFly there are already loggers on the classpath that cause conflicts.  However, when running in JBOSS all parts of the application worked apparently except for POI because DocumentBuilder couldn't find the needed logging dependency on the classpath. Once I reverted the logging exclusions in the POM for JBOSS, it resolved the issue.